# Securing MVC and WebAPI application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api2

I am working on MVC5 and Web API application. Going to use organizational accounts as well as external accounts in that app. I want to know what are the best ways to secure My Web API and MVC application (Authentication and Authorization).

Can we need to add two separate Authentication mechanisms for MVC and WebAPI ?

My Application structure would be below

Application Layer (UI) -> API Layer (Web API) -> Data Access Layer (Models + Entity framework).

Any one suggest me the right direction to secure my application in all aspects.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to

> secure my application in all aspects

is a little bit "wide" as concept.

Anyway, the first and most important thing here is to secure your API access and your application login. I suggest you to implement a full token based authentication which also will give you full access to external auth providers like fb, twitter or even your custom adfs provider.

Check [this](http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/) article for a very nice implementation (I personally made a bunch of app this way with great success).

Second, but not less important, is to use HTTPS. Do not forget about it.

You can also check [IdentityServer](https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/) which can extremely simplify your authentication and authorization layers.

Comment: thanks for your update. I want to know two separate authentications is needed for MVC and Web API ? my project is 3 layer

Comment: Well, it depends. Are you API public? Can you call this API from outside the mvc app or not? If not, you can simply use token auth on the mvc layer. Otherwise you need to secure them both, but you can use auth token for both of them. The simples way is to use API both a consumer and provider of token (oauth consumer/provider). Check the sample app made by Visual Studio with MVC and API enabled.

Comment: thanks for the update.

Comment: we are going to call this API with in the MVC application. so for that two authentications is needed ?

Comment: Is the API reachable from the outside? Can I call directly if I want? Or is behind a firewall or something and it can accept traffic only from the mvc? If the latter, you need to authenticate only the mvc. If not, you need to avoid people from calling directly you api bypassing your login. Otherwise you have to authenticate both the MVC and the API.

Comment: thanks for the update.do you have any idea about best practices of  mvc and webapi. I am creating separate project for each WEB API and MVC. what is the best approach ?can we combine both and create single project.